# making regions using Silvaco ATLAS

Tags: simulation

I am a student majoring in electronic engineering.

Nowadays, I am trying to simulate different forms of MOSFET such as Vaccum FET using Silvaco ATLAS and I need to make triangular or arch(square with half circle at one end) shaped electrode, but I can only make square regions.

I checked the manual but the only other shape I could found rather than square is quadrilateral.

I wish to know if there are only two kinds of regions(square or quadrilateral) provided in ATLAS or there are other ways that I can make triangular or arch shaped regions.

Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

You can make those structures by developing the structure in the DevEdit and importing the structure to Atlas. This is the only option for such structures.